# Which format should I use to save my images in MATLAB?

Tags: python, image, matlab, keras, format

There is 5000 vectors in 1x721 dimension. These vectors are transformed by wavelet transformation to 5000 images with 9x721 dimension in MATLAB. The question is in which format these images should be saved in MATLAB to be used in Keras Python (Spyder) as a two dimension CNN?

Comment: I would use a lossless format such as PNG, and avoid JPEG like the plague. But I don't know much about what you're going to be doing with the data.

Comment: Thank you. I want to classify the data into two classes by convolutional neural network. Is PNG adaptable with keras in spyder?

Comment: Yes, just read it in with PIL and convert to a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

PNG is a lossless image format so it would be perfect for storing your data in images, which can then be read into Python and used by Keras for your CNN

Comment: Hi @Ramin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.